# Starting threads and waiting for them all to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following piece of code (C#): is it correct?

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[totalThread];
            
for (int i=0; i<totalThread; i++) {
   threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
}
    
sw.Start();
    
for (int j=0; j<num_threads; j++) {
   threads[j].Start();
}
                        
           
for (int k=0; k<num_threads; k++) {
   threads[k].Join();    
}
            
sw.Stop();
```

`sw` is a Stopwatch, `work` is some method. I would like to time this method, using a few threads, but the whole thing freezes (seems like it is not joining). I need to know if my thread handling is good, or if I'm screwing up. If the latter, it is obvious that my problem lies in the method I'm calling, rather than in thread mgmt.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you post the code for Work method?

Comment: Why do you use `totalThread` for the first loop and `num_threads` for the next two? Regardless, the problem is likely with your `Work` method, since the above code should be fine.

Comment: Again, without knowing what `DoSomething()` or `DoSomethingElse()` look like, it's hard to say. How big is `totalOperation`? Also, you can just say `op = r.Next(2)`.

Comment: Post the DoSomething() methods, or if they are too big, replace them with dummies. Without them this isn't a real question.

Comment: And, not an answer but you probably shouldn't be using Threads here. Use Tasks if you can (Fx4)

Comment: @Henk. My original question, as far as I can see, is a valid question, with or without the methods. "Is the code I posted correct"? Yes/No. Unless you have redefined the meaning of "question", like Humpty Dumpty :)

Comment: If that was the whole question it would be off-topic. And you still haven't resolved the num_threads/totalThread typo.

Comment: Voting to close as unanswerable, lack of effort etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @Henk Technically I think it would be more for OOT, and to be moved to Codereview

Comment: @xana: Yes, but that's after the last edit/rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfect as it is. I don't see any problem other that the `num_threads`/`totalThread`. Note that if `totalThread` is big (where with big I mean bigger than 1-2 for each CPU Core), you should probably use the [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx).

Comment: I'd like to know the reason for the -1. It isn't any problem, just to know. My response was correct, the suggestion is correct. So?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned freezing.  Try to review your Work method and look for deadlocks. Also, add some timeout mechanism on your Join calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the .Join loop and use a ManualResetEvent in each thread.

You would then wait on the ManualResetEvents to all become signaled.

Comment: Not sure why that would be needed. The above code is fine if the `Work()` method is fine.

Comment: What exactly would be the difference?